# Video concatenation with ffmpeg gives incorrect duration

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation, fluent-ffmpeg

I have a video file and I try to operate with it by means of [fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg). Here is an information which I get about this file with `ffprobe`. You can see that video duration is 6.014s.

```
 { streams: 
   [ { index: 0,
       codec_name: 'h264',
       codec_long_name: 'H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10',
       profile: 'Constrained Baseline',
       codec_type: 'video',
       codec_time_base: '1001/60000',
       codec_tag_string: 'avc1',
       codec_tag: '0x31637661',
       width: 376,
       height: 668,
       coded_width: 376,
       coded_height: 668,
       has_b_frames: 0,
       sample_aspect_ratio: '0:1',
       display_aspect_ratio: '0:1',
       pix_fmt: 'yuv420p',
       level: 30,
       color_range: 'N/A',
       color_space: 'unknown',
       color_transfer: 'unknown',
       color_primaries: 'unknown',
       chroma_location: 'left',
       field_order: 'unknown',
       timecode: 'N/A',
       refs: 1,
       is_avc: 'true',
       nal_length_size: 4,
       id: 'N/A',
       r_frame_rate: '30000/1001',
       avg_frame_rate: '30000/1001',
       time_base: '1/30000',
       start_pts: 0,
       start_time: 0,
       duration_ts: 178200,
       duration: 5.94,
       bit_rate: 1161187,
       max_bit_rate: 'N/A',
       bits_per_raw_sample: 8,
       nb_frames: 178,
       nb_read_frames: 'N/A',
       nb_read_packets: 'N/A',
       tags: [Object],
       disposition: [Object] },
     { index: 1,
       codec_name: 'aac',
       codec_long_name: 'AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)',
       profile: 'LC',
       codec_type: 'audio',
       codec_time_base: '1/44100',
       codec_tag_string: 'mp4a',
       codec_tag: '0x6134706d',
       sample_fmt: 'fltp',
       sample_rate: 44100,
       channels: 1,
       channel_layout: 'mono',
       bits_per_sample: 0,
       id: 'N/A',
       r_frame_rate: '0/0',
       avg_frame_rate: '0/0',
       time_base: '1/44100',
       start_pts: 0,
       start_time: 0,
       duration_ts: 264159,
       duration: 5.99,
       bit_rate: 70594,
       max_bit_rate: 70594,
       bits_per_raw_sample: 'N/A',
       nb_frames: 259,
       nb_read_frames: 'N/A',
       nb_read_packets: 'N/A',
       tags: [Object],
       disposition: [Object] } ],
  format: 
   { filename: '/Users/sergey/Desktop/vid1.mp4',
     nb_streams: 2,
     nb_programs: 0,
     format_name: 'mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2',
     format_long_name: 'QuickTime / MOV',
     start_time: 0,
     duration: 6.014,
     size: 921490,
     bit_rate: 1225793,
     probe_score: 100,
     tags: 
      { major_brand: 'isom',
        minor_version: '512',
        compatible_brands: 'isomiso2avc1mp41',
        encoder: 'Lavf57.25.100' } },
  chapters: [] }
```

However, if I concatenate two such files into a single one:

```
ffmpeg -r 30000/1001 -i /Users/sergey/Desktop/vid1.mp4 -r 30000/1001 -i /Users/sergey/Desktop/vid1.mp4 -y -filter_complex concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 -r 30000/1001 -video_track_timescale 30k /var/folders/8z/5zzmwz4d6mnc2bwfb_1h8jbw0000gn/T/1552213381581.mp4
```

the duration of result **is 12.005 instead of 12.028 expected**:

```
{ streams: 
   [ { index: 0,
       codec_name: 'h264',
       codec_long_name: 'H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10',
       profile: 'High',
       codec_type: 'video',
       codec_time_base: '1001/60000',
       codec_tag_string: 'avc1',
       codec_tag: '0x31637661',
       width: 376,
       height: 668,
       coded_width: 376,
       coded_height: 668,
       has_b_frames: 2,
       sample_aspect_ratio: '0:1',
       display_aspect_ratio: '0:1',
       pix_fmt: 'yuv420p',
       level: 30,
       color_range: 'N/A',
       color_space: 'unknown',
       color_transfer: 'unknown',
       color_primaries: 'unknown',
       chroma_location: 'left',
       field_order: 'unknown',
       timecode: 'N/A',
       refs: 1,
       is_avc: 'true',
       nal_length_size: 4,
       id: 'N/A',
       r_frame_rate: '30000/1001',
       avg_frame_rate: '30000/1001',
       time_base: '1/30000',
       start_pts: 0,
       start_time: 0,
       duration_ts: 358380,
       duration: 11.946,
       bit_rate: 859761,
       max_bit_rate: 'N/A',
       bits_per_raw_sample: 8,
       nb_frames: 358,
       nb_read_frames: 'N/A',
       nb_read_packets: 'N/A',
       tags: [Object],
       disposition: [Object] },
     { index: 1,
       codec_name: 'aac',
       codec_long_name: 'AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)',
       profile: 'LC',
       codec_type: 'audio',
       codec_time_base: '1/44100',
       codec_tag_string: 'mp4a',
       codec_tag: '0x6134706d',
       sample_fmt: 'fltp',
       sample_rate: 44100,
       channels: 1,
       channel_layout: 'mono',
       bits_per_sample: 0,
       id: 'N/A',
       r_frame_rate: '0/0',
       avg_frame_rate: '0/0',
       time_base: '1/44100',
       start_pts: 0,
       start_time: 0,
       duration_ts: 528362,
       duration: 11.980998,
       bit_rate: 70319,
       max_bit_rate: 70319,
       bits_per_raw_sample: 'N/A',
       nb_frames: 517,
       nb_read_frames: 'N/A',
       nb_read_packets: 'N/A',
       tags: [Object],
       disposition: [Object] } ],
  format: 
   { filename: '/var/folders/8z/5zzmwz4d6mnc2bwfb_1h8jbw0000gn/T/1552213381581.mp4',
     nb_streams: 2,
     nb_programs: 0,
     format_name: 'mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2',
     format_long_name: 'QuickTime / MOV',
     start_time: 0,
     duration: 12.005,
     size: 1403350,
     bit_rate: 935177,
     probe_score: 100,
     tags: 
      { major_brand: 'isom',
        minor_version: '512',
        compatible_brands: 'isomiso2avc1mp41',
        encoder: 'Lavf57.71.100' } },
  chapters: [] }
```

I've already looked through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42336195/after-merge-videos-the-duration-is-too-long-ffmpeg) but it seems doesn't help as long as it is exactly the same file so all stats are the same.

So, main questions are "Why result duration differs from sum of two files?" and "How to fix it?".

Could anybody suggest some help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide a link to the input file if possible.

Comment: Here it is: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FRg3rTBsSKgHmYDymoEQld4DBlWtj9ZQ

Comment: Does the input file(s) start and end on a *keyframe* (Iframe) ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question. All the information about the input file (together with itself actually) is available above.

Comment: Hi there, did you ever solve this? Would love if you could share how, if so, as I'm dealing with the same thing.

Comment: @bluepanda No, unfortunately...