# More detail about ffmpeg command

Tags: ffmpeg

In this link [After merge videos, the duration is too long - ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42336195/after-merge-videos-the-duration-is-too-long-ffmpeg) user Gyan has provided a solution shown below

```
ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -s hd720 -r 30000/1001 -video_track_timescale 30k -c:a copy newintro.mp4
```

As the ffmpeg command above did what I was struggling to do, I am eager to learn more. Pointers in that direction will help. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way I could have posted this question such that the person who had provided the original solution (Gyan) would have got alerted to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ffmpeg`
 `-i intro.mp4`  <-- input option and argument (url)
 `-s hd720` <-- video scaling; `hd720` is code for 1280x720. See all codes at http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Video-size
 `-r 30000/1001` <-- set output framerate. This is a rational number; exact representation of 29.97
 `-video_track_timescale 30k` <-- set the [timescale](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43333542/) of the video stream; only applies to MP4 and MOV family of formats.
 `-c:a copy` <-- any audio in output will be copied from source, won't be recompressed. Can only work if source audio codec is supported in output format.
`newintro.mp4` <-- output url, in this case, a MP4 filename.

Comment: Thanks a Ton. The format and detail used for explaining is also very beginner friendly.